# Yii2: Combining Kartik's FileInput & Kartik's DetailView

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2, detailview, kartik-v

I'm trying single-file uploads using Kartik's FileInput.

Things go fine when doing this through standard create form as the following returns **non-null**:

```
$filedata = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'filedata');
```

However it always returns **null** when going into Kartik's DetailView in edit mode and trying to update the file.

In `view.php` I have:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'filedata',
    'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('doIt'),
    'type' => DetailView::INPUT_FILEINPUT,
    'rowOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-view-hidden'],
    'widgetOptions' => ['options' => ['accept' => 'application/pdf'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showUpload' => false,
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['pdf'],
        'initialCaption' => $model->filename,
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'filecleared' => <whatever>,
        'fileloaded'  => <whatever>,
    ],
  ],
],
```

while in `_form.php` (which does work):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'filedata')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
        'options' => ['accept' => 'application/pdf'],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'showUpload' => false,
            'allowedFileExtensions' => ['pdf'],
            'initialCaption' => $model->getOldAttribute('filename'),
        ],
        'pluginEvents' => [
            'filecleared' => <whatever>,
            'fileloaded'  => <whatever>,
        ],
    ]) 
?>
```

Any ideas? (BTW, don't know whether `'multipart/form-data'` is needed somehow in `view.php` as it is in `_form.php`, so anyone confirming this and giving some details should be welcome).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, multipart/form-data is needed both in `_form.php` and `view.php` as well, as follows:

```
'formOptions' => ['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']],
'attributes' => [
...
[
    'attribute' => 'filedata',
    'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('doIt'),
    'type' => DetailView::INPUT_FILEINPUT,
    'rowOptions' => ['class' => 'kv-view-hidden'],
    'widgetOptions' => ['options' => ['accept' => 'application/pdf'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'showUpload' => false,
        'allowedFileExtensions' => ['pdf'],
        'initialCaption' => $model->filename,
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        'filecleared' => <whatever>,
        'fileloaded'  => <whatever>,
    ],
  ],
],
....
]
```